# Installing Git-LFS in Peppermint linux 6

Tags: linux, git, git-lfs

I am trying to install git-lfs in my netbook that runs peppermint 6 linux. I already tryen everything suggested in the documentation but with no luck.

Has anyone knows how to properly  do it?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's good idea to describe exactly what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have already tried everything written on blogs and the git lfs help page. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with help from @PCNetSpec from peppermint os forum

You can find it here:
[link](https://forum.peppermintos.com/index.php/topic,5050.0.html)

Open a terminal and run these commands in sequence:

```
wget https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/packages/ubuntu/trusty/git-lfs_1.5.5_i386.deb/download -O git-lfs_1.5.5_i386.deb
```

followed by:

```
sudo dpkg -i git-lfs_1.5.5_i386.deb
```